# Python get words from textfile and write to sqlite3 db

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a text file with words in a line, e.g.:

`One Two Three`

`Four Five Six`

I need to get every "word" in a seperate colum of the db.

I came up with this code so far:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_command = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id VARCHAR(20),
    second VARCHAR(20),
    third VARCHAR(20),
    fourth VARCHAR(20));"""

    cursor.execute(sql_command)
    query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)"
    filename = open("test.txt", "r")
    with open("test.txt", "r") as filename:
       for data in filename:
          line = data.split()
          print(line)
          cursor.execute(query, data.split(' '))

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

I get the following error message:

`Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied.`

If I change the code to:

`query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL,?,NULL,NULL)"`

the whole line is written to the db:

`1|One Two Three||`

`2|Four Five Six||`

Comment: Is the textfile guaranteed to have the same number of words on every line?

Comment: is your code working , if not what issue you are facing

Comment: Yes, every line has the exact number of words.

Comment: No the code is not working. The "spliting" of the words is not working. The code trys to write the whole line in 1 colum.

Comment: You are not splitting the words with `print(data.split())`, you're just printing them split, you need to store the list, otherwise it's just thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.

tgikal was right. Sorry I didn´t saw your comment.

```
        with open("test.txt", "r") as filename:
        for data in filename:
            line = data.split()
            print(line)
            cursor.execute(query, line)
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write the following for testing and data generation:

```
import sqlite3, os

with open("test.txt", "w") as txt:
  for i in range(10):
  txt.write("One Two Three\n")    

if not os.path.exists("test.db"):
  connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
else:
  os.remove("test.db")
  connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
```

You weren't iterating through lines in the text file. The following is fine:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql_command = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
id VARCHAR(20),
second VARCHAR(20),
third VARCHAR(20),
fourth VARCHAR(20));"""

cursor.execute(sql_command)
query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)"
```

But for the read/write you need to make a change such as this to iterate through lines:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as filename:
  for data in filename:
    line = data.split()
    print(line)
    if len(line) == 3:
        cursor.execute(query, data.split())

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: So then it's not guaranteed to have the same number of words on each line after all... I made an edit

Comment: Also note @C.Vogel that you need to change `cursor.execute(query, data)` to `cursor.execute(query, data.split())`

Comment: I only have two lines in the test file. "one two three" and "four five six". I think the problem is, that the split works only 1 time. I have the auto increment and "one two three" gets written in in colum.

Comment: @C.Vogel I think you need to update your question with some of the information you've been giving in the comments and the progress you've made or nobody will be able to answer. Include sample data